# How to pass Adapter handle to another activity?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have Bluetooth Adapter handle in one activity , how to pass it to another activity.

public BluetoothAdapter BA;

BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

how can i pass this handle to another activity.

Comment: use the same code to get adapter in 2nd activity BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

Comment: @ankitagrawal Thnx man , Its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same code to get adapter in another activity

```
BluetoothAdapter BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```